# How to add a new array to a JSON object without creating duplicate array brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

These nested for loops loop through JSON object containing product categories and subcategories. It loops through these sending a URL parameter to a function to scrape a website according to the parameter. I cant find a way to add the returned arrays containing scraped data to the JSON object (according to its place in the nested loop) without having to create an empty array first and then use .push to populate it, thus duplicating the array brackets. The function returning the scraped data already add the data to an array, so I'm not sure how to go about this.

The following loops add the correct data to the JSON object, however the array brackets are *tripled*.

```
    for (let i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
        let subcats = obj[i].subcategories;

        for(let n=0; n<subcats.length; n++) {

            if(!subcats.facetValueData) {
              subcats[n].code.replace(/\s/g, '')
              let productDataSub = []
              subcats[n].productData = productDataSub
              subcats[n].productData.push(await scrapeData(obj[i].subcategories[n].code))

            } else {
              let subcatsFinal = subcats[n].facetValueData

              for(let p=0; p<subcatsFinal.length; p++) {
                subcatsFinal[p].code.replace(/\s/g, '')
                let productData = []
                subcatsFinal[p].productData = productData
                subcatsFinal[p].productData.push(await scrapeData(obj[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData[p].code))
              
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

The following is the JSON data being looped, the `productData=[]` is an example of where the productData array should go, but it is *not* present when the data is being looped. It is what I'm trying to achieve, but with the data populated inside. The "code" value is the parameter which is appended to a url to scrape that pages data.

```
 [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "categoryName": "Beauty",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "count": 2688,
                "code": "/beauty/skin-care",
                "name": "Skincare",
                "facetValueData": [
                    {
                        "count": 682,
                        "code": "/beauty/skin-care/lotion-serum-and-essence",
                        "name": "Lotion Serum & Essence",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 497,
                        "code": "/beauty/skin-care/moisturiser-and-mist",
                        "name": "Moisturiser & Mist",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 354,
                        "code": "/beauty/skin-care/cleanser-and-exfoliation",
                        "name": "Cleanser & Exfoliation",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 345,
                        "code": "/beauty/skin-care/mask-and-treatment",
                        "name": "Mask & Treatment",
                        "productData": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "count": 1549,
                "code": "/beauty/makeup",
                "name": "Makeup",
                "facetValueData": [
                    {
                        "count": 653,
                        "code": "/beauty/makeup/face",
                        "name": "Face",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 460,
                        "code": "/beauty/makeup/makeup-lips",
                        "name": "Lips",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 337,
                        "code": "/beauty/makeup/eyes",
                        "name": "Eyes",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 124,
                        "code": "/beauty/makeup/makeup-cheeks",
                        "name": "Cheeks",
                        "productData": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "categoryName": "Electronics",
        "subcategories": [
            {
                "count": 526,
                "code": "/electronics/audio-devices",
                "name": "Audio",
                "facetValueData": [
                    {
                        "count": 153,
                        "code": "/electronics/audio-devices/speakers",
                        "name": "Speakers",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 145,
                        "code": "/electronics/audio-devices/earphones",
                        "name": "Earphones",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 142,
                        "code": "/electronics/audio-devices/headphones",
                        "name": "Headphones",
                        "productData": []
                    },
                    {
                        "count": 51,
                        "code": "/electronics/audio-devices/true-wireless-and-airpods",
                        "name": "True Wireless & Airpods",
                        "productData": []
                    }
                ]
            }
                    
        ]
    }
]
```

Not sure if all that necessary but here is the async function which scraped the pages and returns the arrays:

```
async function scrapeData(queryParam) {
    let pageCounter = 0;
    var product = []
    var pagination;

      try {
          do {
            var nextPageLink = `currentPage=${pageCounter}&query=::cagCollectionPoint:Departure+from+Singapore:cagCategory:${queryParam}`
            var nextUrl = url.concat(nextPageLink)

            const response = await axios({
                method: "GET",
                url: nextUrl, 
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: headers
            })
            console.log(nextUrl)
            product.push(response.data["products"])
            pagination = response.data["pagination"]["totalPages"]
            pageCounter++;

            // console.log(response.data.currentQuery.query.value)
            
        } while (pageCounter<=0)

        return product;

      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error)
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the data in order to now what data comes and out ? .

Comment: It would be perhaps better to cache `obj[i].subcategories[n].facetValueData[p]` in a variable, so it`s easier to read and it would be a little faster.

Comment: I have added the JSON plus the function returning the array if it helps.

Thank you I will cache those, I changed it to these values just to make sure there were no issues with the variables as sometimes the async functions were returning "1" instead of the arrays of data... i think it has to do with the duplicate array brackets also